# With JQueryMobile, Facebook JS SDK doesn't work after change page

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, facebook, web-applications

I have an webapp which works with jQuery Mobile (full ajax navigation). I initialize the Facebook SDK at the jQueryMobile's *pageinit* event (each page called).

```
jQuery(document).on('pageinit', function (event) {
    // load FB SDK
    window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
        FB.init({
            appId      : 'MYAPPID',
            channelUrl : '//URL/channel.html',
            status     : true,
            xfbml      : true,
            oauth      : true
        });
        FB.Event.subscribe('auth.authResponseChange', getCurrentUser);
    };
    (function(d, s, id){
        var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
        if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
        js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
        js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js";
        fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
     }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));

    // bind a button to get current user manually
    $('.findme').off('click');
    $('.findme').on('click', getCurrentUser);
});
function getCurrentUser(response) {
    FB.api("/me", function (response) {
        if (window.console && window.console.log) console.log(response.name);
    });
}
```

And HTML contains

```
<button class="findme">Click to get infos about me</button>
```

This code works on the first page. I change page (ajax call), it doesn't work on my second page. I reload (F5) my second page, it works.

Have you ever seen this problem? Have you an idea?

Answer (score 0):

If you use ajax to change pages, you don't have to (and shouldn't) reinitialize the FB SDK every time. Also, you're loading it asynchronously, so it doesn't need to wait for `pageinit`, but you'll need to bind the click event inside the `window.fbAsyncInit` function. That function runs as soon as the FB SDK is loaded.

Answer (score 0):

> Have you ever seen this problem?

I think its the *usual* problem …

> // bind a button to get current user manually
>      $('.findme').off('click');
>      $('.findme').on('click', getCurrentUser);

If you switch out the button for another one, JQuery will not recognize the new button that way. Use `on` in the delegate/live way instead.